# Trouble accessing setting

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, settings

My plugin structure was created by [the plugin factory](https://pluginfactory.io/). I have a setting called ulStateClass and I have been able to change the value of that setting in the Setting for the plug in. Looking at the [3.0 Docs page](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/plugin-settings.md) for settings I see the example:

```
// From your main plugin class:
$foo = $this->getSettings()->foo;

// From elsewhere:
$foo = \ns\prefix\Plugin::getInstance()->getSettings()->foo;
```

My namespace is recoveryfinder\craftnav

In my services php file I have the following to test:

```
echo \recoveryfinder\craftnav::getInstance()->getSettings()->ulStateClass;
```

I am getting the error:

> Error Class 'recoveryfinder\craftnav' not found

Making progress with Craft and enjoying it. I am guessing that this is a misuse or misunderstanding of namespaces? How Do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit confused with your question, if you want to access your settings then you can do craft::$app->plugins->getPlugin('handle')->getSettings()->foo;

Comment: That worked but is very different than the 3.0 docs that I reference.

Comment: If you are calling that method from elsewhere page then you use namespace else you will be using the one that i provided.

Comment: Note: this solution is the slower, performance worse one, that calls the `ns\prefix\Plugin::getInstance()->getSettings()` in the end. I suggest to download a proper IDE that handles all namespaces and includes for you and aceess the plugin directly.

Comment: I am using Netbeans. I am editing the plugin locally and running a LAMP server on my laptop. When I test my code I refresh the page in the browser from my local machine. The code ns\prefix\Plugin::getInstance()->getSettings()->ulStateClass; or recoveryfinder\craftnav::getInstance()->getSettings()->ulStateClass; was not working from my local machine server.

Comment: @robin-schamback I said I was using Netbeans. I suppose I should have said I was abusing Netbeans :)! What do you recommend?

Comment: PhpStrom maybe !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\recoveryfinder\craftnav\Craftnav::getInstance()->getSettings()->ulStateClass;
```

Assuming your main plugin file/class is Craftnav.php

Hope this helps :)